# How do I refresh the columns of a view in SSDT?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-data-tools

I'm getting this error when trying to deploy a SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) database project:

> View or function 'dbo.Employees' has more column names specified than columns defined.

I deleted a column from the underlying table and the view looks like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Employees] AS SELECT * FROM [$(ExternalDB)].[dbo].[Employees];
```

Doing a Google search brings back [this page](http://www.youdidwhatwithtsql.com/view-or-function-dbo-tablename-has-more-column-names-specified-than-columns-defined/546/) which says that SQL Server keeps meta data on views which must be refreshed. They mention this command:

```
EXEC sp_refreshview 'Employees';
```

If I put that in the pre-deployment script, it'll run before the column was dropped. If I put it in the post-deployment script, the deployment will throw the error before it gets executed. So my question is **where or how can I do that with an SSDT project**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is interesting as by default ssdt will refresh any views which depend on any table that has changed as part of a deployment.

Was the column dropped as part of a normal ssdt deployment?

In your publish profile or publish options are you setting ScriptRefreshModule to false?

Aside from this select * in a view is bad practice, put the full column list and this problem disappears, you can even right click the "select *" and choose to expand to get the full column list - do that instead :)
Ed

Comment: The column was dropped as part of the normal ssdt deployment. ScriptRefreshModule is still enabled. I changed the view as you suggested. Thanks once again for your help Ed!